# Getting range_boundaries_to_cidr to run through a vector of data giving the error "Expecting a single value" error

Tags: r, ip-address, cidr

I am creating an R script to manipulate a csv of IP addresses in the format I need it in. An example of the starting csv is as follows:

[image: Ip examples]

```
data2 <- separate(Data,IP,into=c("IP","End"),sep="-")
```

The code above will get it into this format:

[image: IPs after script]

Note: Data is name of CSV and IP is name of the column

After I get to that point I want to use the code below to run through that list and convert the IPs that are not in CIDR format into CIDR format, but it returns the "expecting a single value" error and I am not sure where to go from here. Also, I would like it to skip over the ones that are not in CIDR format and I am not sure if it will do this automatically or I need to code that in as well. I also tried a for loop and got the same error

```
range_boundaries_to_cidr(ip_to_numeric(data2$IP), ip_to_numeric(data2$End))
```

Any help is appreciated!!! I am new to R so I am very open to any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You could try using my [ipaddress](https://davidchall.github.io/ipaddress/) R package. :-)

Starting from your second dataframe, I think the main difficulty is that the `IP` column is sometimes storing an IP address and sometimes storing an IP network. In other words, the data is dirty.

Here's an example with branching logic to handle the two cases.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(withr)
library(ipaddress)

tibble(
  IP = c("192.168.0.0", "172.16.0.0/12", "10.100.56.0"),
  End = c("192.168.55.255", NA, "10.100.56.255")
) %>%
  mutate(network = with_options(list(warn = -1), if_else(
    is.na(ip_network(IP)),
    common_network(ip_address(IP), ip_address(End)),
    ip_network(IP)
  )))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   IP            End                   network
#>   <chr>         <chr>              <ip_netwk>
#> 1 192.168.0.0   192.168.55.255 192.168.0.0/18
#> 2 172.16.0.0/12 <NA>            172.16.0.0/12
#> 3 10.100.56.0   10.100.56.255  10.100.56.0/24
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>